# How to model multiple requirement scenario

Tags: database-design, data-structures, dependencies

I want to store and analyze university course requirements. Lets say, students to register for `ABC123` course following requirements should satisfy.

1. Must pass `CBA321`
2. Should be taken with `XYZ123`
3. Must complete `EFG456`
4. Should have passed 20 credits.

Here I have hundreds of course and similar requirements. My questions are :

- How to model this into a data structure.
- Suitable DB structure (SQL or NOSQL)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind data structures, I'd start with enquiring what the difference is (if any) between "should" and "must". Also, how are the registration rules currently stored and enforced on paper?

Comment: @Stevem Yes, things are paper based now. Difference between should and must is clear. But representing them is the issue.

Comment: So *how* are things currently done on paper - *what* is the structure of those paper records of rules, and how are the rules systematically applied to each course registration? And *what* is the difference between "should" and "must" - *how* does the violation of a "should" rule differ from the violation of a "must" rule?

Comment: @Steve Currently there is a system which does all matching, but its a proprietary and I can not get access or data from it. What I have is just printed materials of existing rules. Basically, MUST rules can not violate, should rules can be violated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're focused on how to represent "must" and "should" rules.

This starts with a data structure containing `Course` (attributes from your description include credits, must_pass...).  I would then structure an intersection entity (`Relationship_Type`) between `Course` and itself.   This will represent the relationships between courses (types such as 'should be taken before', 'must be taken before', 'should be taken with'...).   If two of the same courses can have multiple relationships you'll want to include the type in the key of this relationship.

You can then join through the intersection entity to determine course relationships.